# Export data object from smartcard with OpenSC

Tags: pkcs#11, opensc, pkcs#15

I try to export a data object from a smartcard. For this I am using OpenSC 0.19.0. The command `pkcs11-tool.exe --list-objects` shows that the following data object resides on the token.

```
Data Object 12345678
label: 'mylabel'
application: ''
app_id: <empty>
flags: modifiable
```

`pkcs15-tool.exe --dump` shows a `path` and `data` value of this data object.

`pkcs15-tool.exe --read-data-object mylabel` outputs only the content of the `data` value. I want to export this content to a local file.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two following commands write a data object's content to a local file:

```
pkcs11-tool.exe --module ../pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.dll --login --pin 1234 --read-object --type data --label mylabel --output-file test

pkcs15-tool.exe -read-data-object mylabel -o test
```